# How to change custom attribute value before save it

Tags: magento2, attributes

I need to change the custom attribute added by admin before saving it.

```php
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class MyClass extends AbstractBackend
{

    public function beforeSave($object)
    {
        $object->setData($changedValue);

        return parent::beforeSave($object);
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. You should doing that using backend model.

You need to set value following way:

```
$object->setData('attribute_code', $changedValue);
```